# Is the faces model in Watson studio visual recognition discontinued?

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition, watson-studio

In many tutorials I see the faces model built in to the Visual recognition tool in Watson studio. Ex. https://developer.ibm.com/articles/introduction-watson-visual-recognition/
"Tooling via Watson Studio" -> "Overview".

However I can't seem to find this model when I try to initiate it in Watson studio. The only available models for me are general, food and explicit.

So my question is if the faces model is discontinued?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Faces model was removed from the service. See [this post](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes) in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Visual Recognition (WVR) itself is deprecated. See [FAQs for Visual Recognition](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-vr-use-faqs)